# Programmable access to the right virtual class child?

Tags: c++, qt, virtual, children

I have a virtual / parent class
and many children of this class.
I assume that these children are a different way of generating answers to questions - such as various communication protocols, with one API.
They can have different versions.

```
class A {
 public: virtual const char * [] GetProtocolName () {return "A"; }
 };

class B: public A {
public: virtual const char * [] GetProtocolName () {return "B"; }
};

class C: public B {
public: virtual const char * [] GetProtocolName () {return "C"; }
};
....
```

Let's assume that in the program I want to list my child class / children list - each class has a function:
* char [] GetProtocolName ()

and on the basis of the protocol:
protocol 1

protocol 2

protocol x...

the user can choose by which class the communication should be handled

my question is as follows:

how in the program - ie after the compilation, and how to save it in the code, before compilation - I can determine that the selected class will be the child X of my virtual class / parent - based on text settings (SELECT USER in this list classes).

The problem is 2 things:
how to list each available class as a child of class A, which are available in the program

how to assign a child - choose one protocol from many - based on what you choose from the list (ie on the basis of * char [])
?

```
class * communicationProtocol = ?????
```

I'm brand new in the subject. Thank you for any hint. I do not know what phrase to use, and the phrases I want give me the knowledge I already have.

Comment: To list each availalbe class, which is an child of class A you will need to create this list by your own. To have a list of types(classes) look into `std::tuple`. But all my thinking ends in a big switch-statement to connect pre compilation with post compilation.

Comment: Yes, but having that big switch-statement (which also came in my mind first, when reading the question) seems not to be a great architecture..

Comment: having all your code full of big switch statements is not great, though in some way or another you will need one switch somewhere and thats not a problem. Maybe take a look at the factory pattern

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but a function with a return type of `const char*[]` that returns a string literal seems odd. There may be good reasons for doing that, but it seems much more likely that the function should be `virtual const char* GetProtocolName() { return "A"; }`. And that function should be marked `const`: `virtual const char *GetProtocolName() const { return "A"; }`.

Comment: c++ does not have support to determine the available class names at runtime, however you can help the compiler by having each class that is a candidate for being a child register itself via a static call at the startup of the application, aside from the manual listing proposed by @generic_opto_guy

Comment: another option would be to use 2 build passes to first build your application, run something such as `strings` on the binary, demangle the c++ encoded names, and generate a file which is included in the second build pass which then checks via a template using [is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and possibly other desired [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits). I believe the first build would have to have debug symbols but the second one doesn't need them. Also how you'd pull this off depends greatly on your build system.

Answer (score 0):

O! I found something like here:

```
namespace Ez {

std::shared_ptr<EzGraver> create(QString const& portName, int protocol) {
    qDebug() << "instantiating EzGraver on port" << portName << "with protocol version" << protocol;

    std::shared_ptr<QSerialPort> serial{new QSerialPort(portName)};
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud57600, QSerialPort::AllDirections);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::Parity::NoParity);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::DataBits::Data8);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::StopBits::OneStop);

    if(!serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        qDebug() << "failed to establish a connection on port" << portName;
        qDebug() << serial->errorString();
        throw std::runtime_error{QString{"failed to connect to port %1 (%2)"}.arg(portName, serial->errorString()).toStdString()};
    }

    switch(protocol) {
    case 1:
        return std::make_shared<EzGraverV1>(serial);
    case 2:
        return std::make_shared<EzGraverV2>(serial);
    case 3:
        return std::make_shared<EzGraverV3>(serial);
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument{QString{"unsupported protocol '%1' selected"}.arg(protocol).toStdString()};
    }
}











#ifndef EZGRAVERV1_H
#define EZGRAVERV1_H

#include <QSerialPort>

#include <memory>

#include "ezgraver.h"

namespace Ez {

struct EzGraverV1 : EzGraver {
    using EzGraver::EzGraver;

    /*! Moves the engraver up. */
    void up() override;

...
```

on 
https://github.com/camrein/EzGraver/blob/master/EzGraverCore/factory.cpp

it's almost what I was looking for ... i.e. it does not show the index and i understand that i need to specify this index, but i can see a construction on how to create several protocols :)
thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mix of [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function and [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Add a getter function to your classes that will return the class type (or name if you want to):

```
constexpr static const char *getType()
{
    return 0; // You should use enum here
}
```

Then add a [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function that will check for this value (using a switch case for example):

```
constexpr bool isType() 
{
    return Test::getType() == 0; // Do a real comparison with a templated function for example
}
```

Then use [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to get your type:

```
typedef std::conditional<isType(), int, double>::type Type1;
```

*This code is not to be used like that, but as an example to help you understand what I mean*

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use a "registry". You define a map from the name (that you could ask to the user or read from a file) and a function that creates the appropriate child.

The following is a toy but complete example; note how `main` doesn't need to know the list of all possible derived classes and still can create an object of a given derived class type from its name:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Shape {
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {};
};

struct Triangle : Shape {
    virtual void draw() override { std::cout << "I'm a triangle!\n"; }
};

struct Circle : Shape {
    virtual void draw() override { std::cout << "I'm a circle!\n"; }
};

std::map<std::string, Shape *(*)()> registry{
    {"triangle", []()->Shape* { return new Triangle; }},
    {"circle", []()->Shape* { return new Circle; }}
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "You need to choose the shape type:\n";
        for (auto& i : registry) {
            std::cout << "  " << i.first << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        auto i = registry.find(argv[1]);
        if (i == registry.end()) {
            std::cout << "Unknown shape type\n";
        } else {
            Shape *s = i->second();
            s->draw();
            delete s;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One subtle detail you should pay attention to is that if the derived classes are defined in other compilation units and their registration is also done during static initialization of those units there is formally the risk that the linker will not consider those classes at all unless there is some explicit reference to the units. In other words, suppose you have:

```
 /// File a.cpp
 #include "base.h"
 #include "registry.h"

 struct DerivedA : Base {
     ...
 };

 static int init_a = [](){
     registry["a"] = []()->Base* { return new DerivedA; };
     return 1;
 }();
```

and similar files for all other derived classes.

Then the C++ standard says that it is possible that those classes will not be registered even if you compile them and link them in the program.

This happens because `init_a` initialization can be delayed until the first access to any object in the compilation unit is done. But if `init_a` is not initialized then there's no way someone can access this class because the name will not be in the registry. There's no guarantee that dynamic initialization of static duration objects is performed before the start of `main`, you're only guaranteed that it is performed before any use of any symbol in that compilation unit.

Unfortunately there is no portable `atstart()` in C++.

In other words using self-registering modules (i.e. no reference to any symbol in those compilation units is present anywhere else in the program) is not portable C++. It may work but there's no such a guarantee.

To be safe you should just register all the classes explicitly.